# Reading a sequence of txt files

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I created a set, which has some specific names.
But, these names are text files that I have to read, using the package Pandas.

For example, I can say that my set is like this:

> {0: 'BDS00001',
> 1: 'BDS00002',
> 2: 'BDS00003',
> 3: 'BDS00013',
> 4: 'BDS00014',
> 5: 'BDS00015'
> ...
> 487: 'BDS01952',
> 488: 'BDS01953'}

There is any way that I can use a loop, read the dictionary, transform the **BDS00001** into **BDS00001.txt**, and then read the **BDS00001.txt** using Pandas?

Comment: _" my dictionary is like this:

{XXX0001, XXX0002, XXX0003}"_. This is a `set` not a `dictionary`.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Reading text files using pandas is not easy and also sometimes gives the output you were not expecting.

Comment: I tried some things, but the main problem is that I don't know how to creat a loop to transform BDS00001 into BDS00001.txt

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173586/reading-a-sequence-of-txt-files/72173664#72173664) below.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it doesn't work. Maybe it's because I didn't write a dictionary. The right way to write is { 0: 'BDS00001', 1: 'BDS00002', ...}

Comment: Check now I have edit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
all_files =  { 0: 'BDS00001', 1: 'BDS00002'}

for k,v in all_files.items():
    all_files[k]=v+'.txt'

print(all_files) # {0: 'BDS00001.txt', 1: 'BDS00002.txt'}


#________________________READING FILE________________________#

for a in all_files:
    with open(a) as data:
        print(data.read())
```